# Как установить фон в ячейку QGridLayout?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Необходимо в определенные ячейки QGridLayout установить фон, как это можно сделать?

Я думаю что можно просто вставлять туда QLabel с установленным фоном или QImage но может существует более простой способ без создания дополнительных виджетов?
ячейкам задается фиксированный размер.

Comment: В QGridLayout вы и должны помещать виджеты, фон виджета и будет фоном ячейки.